# Jagged lines on Barcode

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

Trying to insert a barcode into some artwork on Illustrator CC when i try to free rotate the barcode and downsize the lines are becoming jagged? I have anti aliasing checked and the barcode is in an eps format?

Comment: Is it a raster or vector?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your barcode is a bitmap / raster (even if .eps, the format is capable of embedding bitmaps).

If that is the case, you can **solve it by tracing** the barcode first.

1. **LiveTrace** while the barcode is still vertical
2. find the preset that gives best results, check *Ignore White*
3. **Expand**
4. rotate and say goodbye to jaggies, win.

Comment: Very likely; but I'd rather try and regenerate the barcode as an actual vector image first.